# Standard SQL - Delete all rows in table 1 that exist in table 2

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Table 1 has 101,915 rows and Table 2 has 49,466 where all of them exist in Table 1. Table 1 should have 101,915 - 49,466 = 52,449 after the query.

I tried querying a left join but it returns only 8,269 rows.

```
SELECT
  A.*
FROM
  `table1` A
LEFT JOIN
  `table2` B
ON
  A.interval_uid = B.interval_uid
WHERE
  B.interval_uid IS NULL
```

I used interval_uid as key field but all the repeated rows are identical in both tables.

Comment: Have you tried using UNION?

Comment: you can achieve it by using EXCEPT with in CTE , please check my solution.

Comment: Check `interval_uid` dublicates in `table1`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I wanted:

```
WITH
  unwanted_rows AS (
  SELECT
    a.*
  FROM
    `table` a
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      interval_uid,
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      `table`
    GROUP BY
      interval_uid
    HAVING
      COUNT(*) > 1) b
  ON
    a.interval_uid = b.interval_uid
  WHERE
    duration IS NULL
    )
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `table` EXCEPT DISTINCT
SELECT
  *
FROM
  unwanted_rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, If the schema is same, following shall work

```
INSERT INTO `table3` SELECT
   *
FROM
  `table1` A 
 WHERE 
        A.interval_uid NOT IN (SELECT B.interval_uid FROM `table2` B)
```

Comment: My question wasnt clear. I need to remove from table1, not to insert into table3.

Comment: @abutreca you can try to replace the content `INSERT INTO table3 SELECT *` with `DELETE ` and `NOT IN ` with `IN`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using operator **EXCEPT** for SQL. More info needed find [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/except.php)

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3,..
FROM table1
EXCEPT
SELECT col1, col2, col3,..
FROM table2;
```

Insert query as follows:

```
Insert into table3
SELECT col1, col2, col3,..
FROM table1
EXCEPT
SELECT col1, col2, col3,..
FROM table2;
```

Note: Columns specified in the query must be equivalent w.r.to., table1 & table2

Comment: This did the job. I just had to add EXCEPT DISTINCT for BigQuery syntax
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please use below query for your desired result..

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table_1

    EXCEPT

    SELECT *
    FROM Table_2
    )
INSERT INTO Table_3
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

Please try this one if you don't want to insert in table 3.

```
SELECT * FROM Table_1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM Table_2
```

Comment: My question wasnt clear. I need to remove from table1, not to insert into table3.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this following logic-

Note: Delete is a risky operation. Please try with test data first.

```
DELETE table1
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON Table1.interval_uid = Table2.interval_uid
```